# Best Way to Show the Social Icons?

Tags: user-research, social-media

In the right column of my website, I have inserted a social media widget (see attached image).

Should i write some text with the icons or is there another method of identifying these icons to the user?

Also, is the location of the social media widget on my website an optimal location for it?

**Please guide and give me the best of your options for example**

`1. Facebook Page (Icon)` 
Or
`2. Twitter Page (No Icon)`

**Example is highlighted with red in the picture.**
[image: Social Website Icons, Links and Contact Information]

Answer (score 12):

Most users will recognize the logo mark for the social media platforms they use, so additional explanatory text for each icon would be overkill. If you do feel like users might need some additional context, you could use tooltips to display extra text on mouse hover.

The current placement of your social icons seems random. It looks like you placed them in their current location so they'd be above the fold, but having the icons wedged between two site navigation areas breaks apart the navigation too much. I would recommend trying to consolidate your primary navigation elements to the far left column. Due to the number of options you have, you might want to entertain having each category partially collapsed, and only showing the most popular selections users make, with the option of expanding out the full lists to see all available options.

This would free up the far right column, and would allow your social icons to reside beneath your site search. Best of luck on your project!

Comment: +1 Society is pretty much trained to see those as either "Like" or "Follow".

Comment: Thanks @ChrisK and everyone for your answer but i found all the answers correct. i am novice so how can i judge people who are more experienced than me. I mean how can i accept the only one answer

Answer (score 11):

It is perhaps not necessary to write out the label Facebook or Twitter next to the icon as Chris stated in his previous answer.

But, please  **explain why I should follow you** on Facebook. Is it for getting great discounts? Is it because you post new outfits that I can use for inspiration? Is it because I no longer need to go to your web site for updates?

If you only show the icons, only the die hard fans of you brand or some opportunists will click on them. Explain the benefits and sell it. Everybody wins. That's the way to get more followers.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'll be completely honest. I definitely agree with Chris on the navigation, but let's think about this for a second.

I think the big question here falls back to, "Who is the audience?"

If the audience is a consumer and they're purchasing something from you ( also depending on what that something is ), will really depend on where you place those social icons.

Seeing that this is for fashion, I would always do some kind of UX Research that would pose theories based on the data I've gathered from any and all sources. After comparing and contrasting to competitors, I would then move into analysis to match the over all goals.. which falls back to the target audience.

Example:

Companies like Vogue place their social media in the footer, since this is where users will most likely look, and if not in the footer, then it will most definitely be in the header.

Taking that a step further, we now have another contender like the Men's Warehouse. Same industry, different sector, different audience. However, they too have their social media icons in the footer, why is this?

The reason for that, is because it goes back to the comment Chris made about consolidating the navigation, there are a lot of options here and possibly playing around with that might provide a better solution to your overall end goal. The Men's Warehouse may have in fact wanted the user to really focus on their deals, sales and product. Which that exactly is what they've put out there.

This of course is just my opinion and some may agree or disagree, but at the very least there seems to be some strong holding evidence there. :)

I wish you the best of luck on your project!

For reference, here are url's to both the Men's Warehouse and Vogue:

http://www.menswearhouse.com/ and
http://www.vogue.com/

Answer (score 1):

For social services the icons will be enough. Users of the services will have a good understanding of what the icon does, and the title above them just confirms the purpose.

For the telephone icon I wouldn't know what that does. When I'm on a smartphone, does that bring me to the telephone app?

The placement of the icons is a whole other story. It requires some research like a usability test to know if users see and use them.